# Keras Graph disconnected

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Well, I have a problem setting up a network consisting of a CNN + Autoencoder for a classification task. The main idea is to use CNN-generated embedding as the input of an autoencoder for the embedding reconstruction process. Well, I was able to define both architectures, but I couldn't merge them into a single graph.

```py
def autoencoder(cnn_out):
        xreal = keras.layers.Input(tensor=cnn_out)
        (...)
        xhat = keras.layers.Dense(cnn_out.shape[1], activation='sigmoid')(dec)

        ae = keras.models.Model(inputs=xreal, outputs=xhat)
        loss_mse = mse_loss(xreal, xhat)
        ae.add_loss(loss_mse)
        return ae

def cnnae_model(input_shape):

        h1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(8,strides=(1,1), kernel_size=kernel, kernel_regularizer=r.l2(kl), padding='same')(X)
        (...)
        h5 = keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))(h5)

        xreal = keras.layers.Flatten()(h5)

        cnn = keras.models.Model(inputs=X, outputs=xreal)

        cnn_ae = keras.models.Model(inputs=cnn.input, outputs=autoencoder(cnn.output).output)

        return cnn_ae

input_shape = (128, 64, 3)
model = cnnae_siamesa(input_shape)
model.compile(loss=contrastve_loss,bacth_size = 16, optimizer=rms, metrics=[accuracy], callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```

The following error message appears when I try to compile the model:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("flatten_11/Identity:0", shape=(None, 2048), dtype=float32) at layer "input_50". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some modifications to your code and produced a working version (one without the error you reported).  There are a few changes that have to do with how the output layers are called when connecting up the different submodels, but hopefully you can relate it back to your original model.  There is some additional information here that might help clarify: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#using_the_same_graph_of_layers_to_define_multiple_models.  I hope this helps. :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

print(tf.__version__)
tf.keras.backend.clear_session() 

# Code with issue:
def autoencoder(cnn_out):
        xreal = cnn_out # tf.keras.layers.Input(tensor=cnn_out)
        dec = xreal
        xhat = tf.keras.layers.Dense(cnn_out.shape[1], activation='sigmoid', name='AE_Dense')(dec)
#        ae = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=xreal, outputs=xhat, name='AE_Model')       
#        loss_mse = mse_loss(xreal, xhat)
#        ae.add_loss(loss_mse)
        return xhat  # return last layer of model

def cnnae_model(input_shape):

#CNN model start:
        X = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape, name='CNN_Input')
        h1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,kernel_size=(2,2), padding='same', name='CNN_Conv2D')(X)
        h5 = h1
        h5 = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), name='CNN_AvgPooling2D')(h5)
        xreal = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name='CNN_myFlatten')(h5)
        cnn = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=X, outputs=xreal, name='CNN_Model')
#CNN model end:
        ae_model = autoencoder(xreal)
        cnn_ae = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=cnn.input, outputs=ae_model, name='cnn_ae_model')
        return cnn_ae

input_shape = (128, 64, 3)
model = cnnae_model(input_shape)
print('model.summary():')
print(model.summary())

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
x_train=np.random.random((2,128,64,3))
y_train=np.random.random((2,16384))

print('x_train.shape:')
print(x_train.shape)
print('y_train.shape:')
print(y_train.shape)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I adapted your code to my problem and it worked perfectly. Thanks also for the explanatory link.